# How to make the ion-nav transparent?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I want to ion header or nav transparent, so I can something like shown on the picture. But setting the background-color to transparent does not solve the problem. The content should be "fullscreen" than. If possible, the content should be behind the status bar.

[image]

Comment: first of all you have to set full image into your page background and then upon the all components buttons and header you have to set css opacity property. ex.  opacity: 0.5;

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So there are a few things you need to do. First, as Dennis said, I wrote a little tutorial for setting the headers as transparent, which you could check in detail [here](https://yannbraga.com/2017/03/16/how-to-transparent-header-ionic2/).

- So first you add the `transparent` input property to your `nav-bar`, which basically adds `background:transparent !important` to the toolbar.
- Also you can remove the border-shadow which is shown on android by adding `no-border` to your `ion-header`.
- Then you'd want to remove the top-padding on `.scroll-content`, so the header padding is ignored. To do so, just add `top-padding: 0`.
- If you wish to add a gradient layer over the slides, you'd have to work on `.slide-zoom`, which is generated automatically by `ion-slide`. You can set its height as 100% as well as width then add something like `background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(226, 135, 106, 0.84) 0%, rgba(255, 93, 152, 0.85) 100%) !important;`
- To change the bullets style you have to use `.swiper-pagination-bullet` and `.swiper-pagination-bullet-active`.

I wrote a really quick example trying to achieve what you wish:

[image]

If this is what you wish, I [published a repo](https://github.com/yannbf/ionicTransparentHeaderSample) so you can use it as reference.

Comment: Thanks for disclosing your affiliation with your links. If you haven't already, I'd recommend reading [How not to be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) -- you're currently following it, but it's good to know what the rules are.

Comment: Hey @qpaystaxes thanks for that! I actually didn't know about the rules. I edited the post to be even more disclosed. Cheers!

Answer (score 7):

I have found a really nice solution: [Tutorial](https://yannbraga.com/2017/03/16/how-to-transparent-header-ionic2/)

1. You can easy edit the ion-header: `<ion-header no-border>` (delete the border on android devices)
2. Add the **transparent** attribute to the navbar: `<ion-navbar transparent>`

Answer (score 4):

[This](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/content/Content/#input-properties) is what you're looking for:

> By default, content is positioned between the headers and footers.
>   However, using `fullscreen="true"`, the content will be able to scroll
>   "under" the headers and footers. At first glance the fullscreen option
>   may not look any different than the default, however, by adding a
>   transparency effect to a header then the content can be seen under the
>   header as the user scrolls.

So you just need to add `fullscreen="true"` in your content like this

```
<ion-content fullscreen="true">
  <!-- ... -->
</ion-content>
```

Comment: My current problem: Ionic automatically creats a scroll-content child. This has a padding-top. I could solve this css but I think it's a better idea to disable this child element? Do you know how to do?

Comment: To remove top padding from ion-content, remove the `padding` attribute directive from ion-content

Comment: The most elegant (and perhaps "correct"?) solution I've seen so far anywhere.

Comment: So glad to hear that @ThisIsNotAnId :)

Comment: Its not working on device or simulator. But it works on browser simulators through ionic serve. Can you please tell me how to achieve the transparency on device/simulator as well.